# Signal Compressing

Tags: python, signal-processing, python-2.5

I need to "compress" the size of python arrays which represent signals. The signals look like following example.

```
signal = [
    [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1], #time values
    [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,2,1,1] #function values
    ]
```

After compressing, the signal should look like in following code.

```
signal_compressed = [
    [0.0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1], #time values
    [1,1,2,3,4,4,2,1,1] #function values
    ]
```

You see, if there are areas with constant values, only the first and the last value of this area is stored.

I wrote following algorithm to do this.

```
signal_compressed = [[],[]]

old_value = None
for index, value in enumerate(signal[1]):
    if value != old_value:
        if index > 0:
            if signal_compressed[0][-1] != signal[0][index - 1]:
                signal_compressed[0].append(signal[0][index - 1])
                signal_compressed[1].append(signal[1][index - 1])
        signal_compressed[0].append(signal[0][index])
        signal_compressed[1].append(value)
        old_value = value

if signal_compressed[0][-1] < signal[0][-1]:
    signal_compressed[0].append(signal[0][-1])
    signal_compressed[1].append(signal[1][-1])
```

This algorithm works fine. And for signals with lot of constant segments he works quite fast. But if I try to compress signals with no constant segments (e.g. a sine signal or a noise signal), the algorithm works really slow.

How can I accelerate my algorithm and conserve the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using a generator:

```
def compress(signal):
    prev_t, prev_val = None, None
    for t, val in zip(*signal):
        if val != prev_val:
            if prev_t is not None:
                yield prev_t, prev_val
            yield t, val
            prev_t, prev_val = None, val
        else:
            prev_t, prev_val = t, val
    if prev_t is not None:
        yield prev_t, prev_val

signal = [
    [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1], #time values
    [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,2,1,1] #function values
    ]
print zip(*compress(signal))
```

I think it would be more natural to transpose `signal`, storing it like so:

```
[(0.0, 1),
 (0.1, 1),
 (0.2, 1),
 (0.3, 2),
 (0.4, 3),
 (0.5, 4),
 (0.6, 4),
 (0.7, 4),
 (0.8, 4),
 (0.9, 2),
 (1.0, 1),
 (1.1, 1)]
```

This way the two `zip(*seq)` calls would be unnecessary and the entire processing can be done on the fly.

Finally, if this is still too slow for large input, it might be worth looking into using NumPy. Here is an outline of one such solution:

```
import numpy as np

signal = [
    [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1], #time values
    [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,2,1,1] #function values
    ]

def npcompress(signal):
    sig=np.array(signal)
    idx = np.where(sig[1][1:] != sig[1][:-1])[0]
    idx_arr = np.sort(np.array(list(set(idx) | set(idx + 1) | set([0]) | set([len(sig[1]) - 1]))))
    return sig.T[idx_arr]

print npcompress(signal).T
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your algorithm and compared it with mine. For short signals your algorithm is faster. But for large inputs it is slower than mine. Could you please explain the solution with `NumPy`more detailed?

Comment: @wewa: I've added an outline of one such solution that has no Python loops in it.

Comment: I also tried this new algorithm with `NumPy`. It is a little bit faster then mine. But only if you don't transform the numpyarrays back to lists. Is there any other possibility to compress my data?

Comment: I've now tested your `numpy` algorithm with the help of `timeit` and with more than one execution, your algorithm is much faster than mine.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
In [93]: from itertools import groupby

In [94]: from operator import itemgetter

In [95]: ti=[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1]

In [96]: fun=[1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,2,1,1]

In [97]: def func(ti,func):
    new_time=[]
    new_func=[]
    for k,v in groupby(enumerate(func),itemgetter(1)):
       lis=list(v)
       if len(lis)>1:
           ind1,ind2=lis[0][0],lis[-1][0]
           new_time.extend([ti[ind1],ti[ind2]])
           new_func.extend([func[ind1],func[ind2]])
       else:    
           new_time.append(ti[lis[0][0]])
           new_func.append(func[lis[0][0]])
    return new_time,new_func
   ....: 

In [98]: func(ti,fun)
Out[98]: ([0.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1],
          [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your interesting solution. But also this algorithm is not faster than mine.

Comment: @wewa Using which method did you time these different solutions?

Comment: `st = time.clock()
cs1 = func(signal)
t1 = time.clock()-st`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting in the comment above. [Here](http://chopapp.com/#l5qq3vrs) you can see the method I used to measure time (click on "Here").

Comment: @wewa don't use `time.clock()` for timing, python has a dedicated module for this : [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I've now tested the algorithms with `timeit`. With only one execution, my algorithm is the fastest. But from 2 executions NPE's algorithm with `numpy` is the fastest.